# How do I get the position of an element after css3 translation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I saw this posted in 2 different forms on stackoverflow, but the solutions don't work for me.

Essentially, I have an item that I will translate.  When I do a obj.style.left or obj.offsetLeft, after the element has been translated, I get 0.  Is there anyway I can get the coordinates/position of an element after it has been translated with css3?

I can't use jQuery (because I can't and also because I want to understand the solution, not just use the library without understanding what is happening underneath)

Any ideas?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect()`:

Imagine the following html block:

```
<div class="centralizer popup">
    <div class="dragger"></div>
</div>
```

And the style:

```
body {
    background:#ccc;
}
.centralizer {
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:170px;
    width:352px;
    height:180px;
    overflow:auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
.popup {
    background:white;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius:3px;
}
.dragger {
    background:#eee;
    height:35px;
    border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Now you can use the following javascript to get the correct position:

```
var popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
var rect = popup.getBoundingClientRect();

console.log("popup.getBoundingClientRect(): \n" + "x: " + rect.left + "\ny: " + rect.top);
```

You can check the result in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tr_bustamante/Y2naL/2/):

I tested on FF, IE and chrome, and it worked on all my tests.

Comment: Awesome! And +1 for browser compatibility!

Comment: This isn't working for me in iOS8+, apparently due to a known issue with getBoundingClientRect().

Comment: This is great and works after multiple transforms to parents as well. Wish that was the accepted answer.

Comment: what about 3D transforms?

Comment: I tested this out with css3 transform perspective - works great https://jsfiddle.net/qdhv1uzr/

Answer (score 22):

Ok, hold tight because this is not nice:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  var node = document.getElementById("yourid");
  var curTransform = new   WebKitCSSMatrix(window.getComputedStyle(node).webkitTransform);
  console.log(node.offsetLeft + curTransform.m41); //real offset left
  console.log(node.offsetTop + curTransform.m42); //real offset top
});
```

You can play with it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/duopixel/wzZ5R/

Comment: what about non webkit browsers?

Comment: I can't find any documentation for the equivalent of WebkitCSSMatrix on other browsers, I've seen code where the author "saves" a copy of the transform into a data attribute in order to read it later, such as `<div class="transformed" data-rotate="45deg">`

Comment: Note that this does not recursively get the transform of the node. This means that if one of the node's ancestors is translated, it will not be reflected in the node's transform matrix. You will get a wrong offset in that case.

Comment: yep; what about non webkits browsers ?

Comment: **Answer below is better.**

Comment: This is the most convoluted code I've seen in a while (not yours, from the browser, that param of m41 sealed the deal) .  Have an upvote.

Comment: This is now supported in most browsers as `DOMMatrix`.