# Retrieving correct offsetTop and offsetLeft of an element after a CSS3 rotation

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking for a way to get correct offsetTop / offsetLeft values (or similar) of an element after performing a transform rotation.

Is this possible? Are there any other element properties which i'm not aware of?

I have included an image which might help in explaining the issue.

[image: Diagram demonstrating offsetTop and offsetLeft before and after a MozTransform rotation]

Comment: Not only that, but what about height and width?

Comment: From experience, this varies from browser to browser as well.  Some return pre-transform offsets and some return post-transform offsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS3's strange animations does not tell you the changed positions after you have performed a webkit transform animation.

However, this link might be of help.

[How do I get the position of an element after css3 translation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975727/how-do-i-get-the-position-of-an-element-after-css3-translation-in-javascript)

thanks