# How do I know if a particular item has left the container?

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I wrote a small [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbWomY)

```
$('#block_container').addClass('animate');
var el = $('.block__el');
var height = el.height();
var allHeight = height * el.length;
$(".animate").css('transform', 'translateY(-'+ allHeight +'px)')
```

Also I can not understand as to me to deduce the message that for example the item[10] left a zone of visibility of the container.

I tried via `offsettop`, but this is not the right way

Comment: By comparing position of the element ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the position of an element after css3 translation in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975727/how-do-i-get-the-position-of-an-element-after-css3-translation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question (getting element position when using translateAxis in CSS) was more or less answered in this post:

[How do I get the position of an element after css3 translation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975727/how-do-i-get-the-position-of-an-element-after-css3-translation-in-javascript)

However, if you need to closely track elements, I would highly advise using Javascript to manipulate them around the page instead of CSS, its faster, easier and more homogenous across browsers.

Changing the state of the DOM with CSS and trying to catch that with javascript is a bit of an anti-pattern unless writing the equivalent javascipt would be really hard.

Answer (score -1):

In your calculations, you have to count borders. Each item has a border of 1px width, so each item has 2px more than the height property.

If you give all elements `box-sizing: border-box`, then height will be calculated with borders, and your example will work:

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```