# Difference between getBoundingClientRect().top and offsetTop?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between getBoundingClientRect().top and offsetTop?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWZWQg

```
const elem = document.querySelector('#find');

console.log('getBoundingClientRect: ' + elem.getBoundingClientRect().top);

console.log('offsetTop: ' + elem.offsetTop);

// Stuff to push the div down the page
<div id='find'>Find me</div>
```

From my quick test the only difference seems to be the number of decimal places returned.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`getBoundingClientRect` gives you offset relative to your client viewport, While `offsetTop` is always fixed static property. although it changes when the actual position of the element changes on document. For real clarification go to pen and you can check the difference your self.

If element is inside relative container then `offsetTop` will be relative to the given container
[pen](https://codepen.io/MehulJoshi/pen/QvovPq)

```
console.log('offsetTop: ' + elem.offsetTop); //This is fixed. it get's calculated from beginning of your page to actual element's position.

console.log('getBoundingClientRect: ' + elem.getBoundingClientRect().top); // this will changing while scroll, because it's relative to your current view port.
```

see the pen, scroll the div and while doing that check the console.

In case container of the element is relative then

```
console.log('offsetTop: ' + elem.offsetTop) // //This is fixed. it get's calculated from beginning of your top most relative container.
```

Comment: @Enthu you already have valid answer, if you need more info will be happy to help.

Comment: yeah that post gives the answer and it is working for what I had asked , however I need one more thing , on mousemove I am able to calculate the top, left , what can be done if on drop of the element itself I can get the top,left value .If you can give any suggestion else if you want I can create a new post. Thanks

Comment: This is wrong. `offsetTop` calculates from parent with position relative so if you will wrap element with parent which has position: relative it will calculate from it rather than from page top. As in MDN: "The HTMLElement.offsetTop read-only property returns the distance of the current element relative to the top of the offsetParent node." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop

Comment: @Aivus answer is relevant to the question in the pen. mdn has more generic answer, and answer is completely wrong, yes it has missing details related to position relative. but yes it's more about question asked by user.

Answer (score 17):

The `HTMLElement.offsetTop` read-only property returns the distance of the current element relative to the top of the offsetParent node.

`getBoundingClientRect()` is a very useful, cross browser safe method that returns top, right, bottom, and left position of any element relative to the viewport.

Answer (score 4):

The method `getBoundingClientRect` may not be as good in performance as offsetLeft ([doc here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/optimize-javascript-execution?hl#avoid_micro-optimizing_your_javascript)), but if you wanna know an element's position after it transformed by CSS, or even still in transition animation, it is the best choice (maybe the only way).
Here is a [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22360535/7526989).