# Can animation only be applied to 'absolute' positioned elements?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to animate an object using DOM and struggling to animate the element when its CSS property *position* is not set to "absolute". Here is my code below:

I create a circle HTML element and try to move it in 45 degrees. Is there any way to animate an HTML element object that is not positioned **absolute**?

```js
 x = 10;
    
function on_click() {

    var myCurvyMovement = document.getElementById("circle");
    myCurvyMovement.style.left = 0.5 * x;
    myCurvyMovement.style.top = 1 + x

    x += 10;

}
```

```css
 #circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

/* Cleaner, but slightly less support: use "50%" as value */
#divBox {
    position: static
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button style="display:block" onclick="on_click()">Move the box</button>
    <div id="circle">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you can position it as fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't consider `left`/`right` in order to do animation. As you have noticed, it won't work in all the cases as it need positionned elements. Even when using positionned element you won't have the same behavior between `relative`, `absolute` and `fixed` because each one will have its own reference for `top`/`left`.

For such case better consider [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) that you can apply to any element ([shouldn't be an inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54227332/8620333)) and the reference of the movement will be the same for all. You will also have better performance.

```js
x = 10;
    
function on_click() {

    var myCurvyMovement = document.getElementById("circle");
    myCurvyMovement.style.transform = "translate(" + (0.5 * x)+"px,"+(1 + x)+"px)";
    x += 10;

}
```

```css
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition:0.5s all; /*to have a smooth movement*/
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button style="display:block" onclick="on_click()">Move the box</button>
    <div id="circle">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer seems good but eventually when I did a periodic animation setInterval(on_click, 20); it halts animation after first iteration. Don't know why

Comment: @muhammadtayyab you are not changing the variable of transform .. you need to store them to use theme again. OffsetLeft and offsetTop has nothing to do with translation and will never change.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to change

Comment: @muhammadtayyab use variable like you did here and increase them. it's the simpliest way

Comment: Thanks, I will checkout why transform don't trigger offsetLeft and offsetTop values to change.

Comment: @muhammadtayyab because this is the pupose of transform. It doesn't change the layout and the dom, it's only a visual transformation .. so left/top of your element will not change, it's different from using top/left because top/left will change the DOM and the *real* element position

Comment: @muhammadtayyab check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975727/how-do-i-get-the-position-of-an-element-after-css3-translation-in-javascript it may give you ideas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189441/discussion-between-muhammad-tayyab-and-temani-afif).

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to concatenate the "px" to set the x and y positions

```js
 x = 10;
    
function on_click() {

    var myCurvyMovement = document.getElementById("circle");
    myCurvyMovement.style.left = 0.5 * x + 'px';
    myCurvyMovement.style.top = 1 + x + 'px';

    x += 10;

}
```

```css
 #circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

/* Cleaner, but slightly less support: use "50%" as value */
#divBox {
    position: static
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button style="display:block" onclick="on_click()">Move the box</button>
    <div id="circle">
    </div>
</body>
```

when not's absolute you need change the margin-left and margin-top property, in javascript is like this 
`myCurvyMovement.style.marginLeft = 1 + x + 'px'`

`myCurvyMovement.style.marginTop = 1 + x + 'px'`

(top/bottom and left/rigth)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking if it's possible to animate when css property is not set to absolute

Comment: Oh yes, when not's absolute you need change the `margin-left` and `margin-top` property, in javascript is like this `myCurvyMovement.style.marginLeft = 1 + x + 'px`
`myCurvyMovement.style.marginTop = 1 + x + 'px`

(top/bottom and left/rigth)

Comment: @TheDev that will effect the relative elements around the animated element, if the animated element is also relative.

Comment: @vikrant Yes, but it's possible thank you for the edit brother!