# How to position div that follows the cursor in a virtual scroll context

Tags: javascript

I'm building a site where the browsers scroll is manipulated in order to get the content to ease on scroll in a very nice way. I'ts all built utilising the `transformY` property. Further down on the page i got this element that when `onEnter, onMove` occurs is going to follow along with the mouse position - which I'm struggling with, since `clientY` does not really make any sense/is off because the implementation of the `transformY`.

How can i solve this? I guess that i somehow have to take the `translateY` in consideration when doing the positioning? As well as the height of the `<section>`? I'll add the relevant code below together with some comments to better understand.

Markup:

```
<main> //wrapper for the content.
  <section style="transform: translateY(-317px);"> //content holder,

      -317px is just a dummy value to demo how it works, it gets set by a variable.

      // divs of content

      <div class="my-el">
          some text
      </div>

      // more divs of content

  </section>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
main {
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS that i try to use to solve the problem:

```
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMove)

  onMove(e) {
    const el = e.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('.my-el')
    gsap.to(el,{
      x:e.clientX,
      y:e.clientY
    })
  }
```

Comment: I think this probably answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22360535/1086398

Comment: Hm, not so sure about that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Actually, after a bit of fiddling it did the trick!